# JavaFX application icon & title bar icon with native packaging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am using Eclipse Luna I can create icon & png images
these were placed in a folder named Photos under src/appCSVFile/Photo/image.png
The title bar icon is displayed at design time but not when the application is packaged 
as a EXE file.

this is the line of code that works at design time
pStage.getIcons().add(new `Image("file:src/appCSVFile/Photos/AFXCsvProject.png"));`

Can someone suggest the correct folder to place the icon or png files in for deployment?
I would like to change the title bar icon and the application install icon.
I am naming the icon with the application title as suggested in code.makery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Native Package deployment steps with Eclipse Luna

Create an AFX Csv Project with Eclipse
Right click the src folder and add a folder named Photos, this will hold the `merlin.gif` with the path set by Scene Builder.

Right click on the project in the Package Explorer, then choose `New > Source Folder` and add a source folder named `resources`.
To the resources folder add a folder named `images`.
Paste the the title bar bitmap to this folder (`C.bmp` worked as did `AFXCsvProject.bmp`).
`C.bmp` was created with GreenFish Icon Maker 32 by 32 (no spaces in the bmp name).

Open **`build.fxbuild`**

```
Vendor Name = 
Application Title = AFX Csv Project
Application Class = appCSVFile.CSVMain
Packaging Format = exe
```

Open **`build.xml`** and add the two lines below

```
<file name="${basedir}"/>
<fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>
```

Run "Generate ant build.xml onl".
Right click on the generated build folder, add a folder named `dist`
and paste the `resource` folder from the main application.

Now you have a AFX Csv Project.jar file
Add this to the Build Path by Right Clicking it and Configure Build Bath
under the Library TAB click Add JAR and navigate to the JAR file

Open build.fxbuild
And Click ant.build only

Open build.xml file and add the two lines below

```
<file name="${basedir}"/>
<fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>
```

Right Click build.xml and select Run As 1.Ant Build

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to place your icons and resource files in another folder than `src`. For example `/resources/icons` placed at the root of the eclipse project.
Then, you have to set that folder as source folder for the project build path. The last thing you have to do is add 2 lines in the build.xml file located at the `build` folder in the root of the project.

- Look for the `<filelist>` tag and write `<file name="${basedir}"/>` inside of the block
- Look for the `<fx:resources id="[your project's name]>`tag and write `<fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>` inside of the block.

These two lines are not generated when you run the JFX Run deployment, so you will have to add then **every time** you deploy the project.

Comment: Error Report  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
do-deploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\User Name\workspace\AFX Csv Project\build\build.xml:98: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:resources
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

Comment: Error Report  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
do-deploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\User Name\workspace\AFX Csv Project\build\build.xml:98: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:resources
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet